# ASP.NET MVC with Facebook Connect template project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, facebook

I'm looking for template project that uses Facebook Connect instead of ASP.NET Membership service with ASP.NET MVC 1.0/2.0/3.0. It should support connect (login) and logof and storing user data to the database. Is there something like that?

And second question: Would YOU like to participate in building such tamplate? (if similar project doesn't exist)

Comment: building template is hard and useless sometime better when you need them. you can make your own if you want !

Comment: let me know, if you are willing to start this project.

Comment: well, i think that we should google it little bit more.. and try to find something similar.. a know that many developers need this so i think this could be a very usefull project..

Comment: I doubt there is anything out there -but it wouldn't be hard to use the Facebook C# SDK - and simply persist the details to the DB once you get them.

Comment: A good starting point may be dotnetopenauth (http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/).  They have a few project templates you may be able to fork and add Facebook Connect stuff (https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/).

Comment: OpenAuth is over-kill. I used the FB C# sdk and got simple view working in about 15 minutes. It's really easy.

Answer (score 2):

Not a template, but take a look at [Janrain Engage](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage). It's a connector for several social networking sites, Facebook included.

Comment: So, you know, seems a common courtesy would be to leave a comment when you're demoting someone's response. I'm not entirely sure why offering up potential resources for the project the author is suggesting would warrant a demotion. I think it was pretty clear that it wasn't a direct solution to his problem.

Comment: Agreeing with @mannish. (I'm the one who set you back to zero, he didn't removed his -1 by now)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this one http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/